Flutter Web does not render after calling html.window.location.href
Using Flutter v3.19.5,
In my Flutter WEB App I have to navigate to a html.window.location.href (due to some payment-API). And when I try to return to my actual Flutter App and render the successURL screen, it just does not work.
The API call works fine. And its successUrl is called.
I end up with a localhost that looks like this:
http://localhost:61344/#/principles_main
And
Inside my onGenerateRoute I can set my App path by observing the #-route of this successURL.
I then try to replace the html.window.location.href again to show a success-page as such:
html.window.location.hash = '/principles_main';
html.window.location.reload();
return const PrincipleMain();

After this, I end up with an local URL that looks like this:
http://localhost:61344/#/principles_main
But this does not do anything! The App freezes ! No error message at all.
And worst of all: the intended PrincipleMain widget is not shown !
In addition, I am using the FlutterWebPluginWeb as such:
import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

class FlutterWebPluginWeb {
  static void resetRoute() {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      setUrlStrategy(null);
    }
  }
}

What can I do to make the Flutter WEB App come back to rendering normal pages after the successURL html.window.location.href navigation ?????????

An observation: the reload() only works if I set the html.window.location.hash = ''. And it only does it after about 15 seconds !!!!! (i.e. Flutter WEB is awfully slow when reloading a page).  I am completely clueless why Flutter v3.19.5 does not allow reloads of other hash-locations ????

Never mind - it was all my mistake !!! I am sorry about any confusion it might have caused.
The reason why the html.window.location would not work was that I am using flutter_native_splash in my main.dart. And in case the payment-API has finished and the flutter App has returned to the successURL, I HAD FORGOTTON TO ADD FlutterNativeSplash.remove(); method. (i.e. it had perfectly worked - but the Splashscreen kept beeing shown and I assumed the app had freezed).
Again, I am sorry for any confusion. This ticket can be closed.
